# PHP parse_ini_file and includes not working (Ubuntu desktop LAMP )

Tags: php, ubuntu

New here, and PHP's a new language to me. I'm trying to develop a web app. To keep things secure, I'm trying to save my database login credentials in a simple ini file (called db.ini).

1)  My system is running Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed LAMP

2) The script, which updates a database via mysqli_connect and mysqli_query, works fine when I have login credentials in the myqli_connect script pasted below. Note, for troubleshooting I'm echoing a message upon successful connection:

```
$db = 'my_db';
$db_use = 'my_root_user';
$db_pass = 'my_password';
$db_host = 'localhost:3306';

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_use, $db_pass, $db);
if(! $conn) 
    {die('Could not connect connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()) ;
} else
    {echo ("Success");
}
```

3) I created a db.ini file for security reasons. Though I plan to move it later, I've stored in in the same directory as my .php script:  (\var\www\html\my_site).

Here's how the .ini reads

```
[database]
host = localhost:3306
username = my_root_user
password = my_password
dbname = my_database
```

3) I have tried to parse this file via the following methods. All have failed at print_r, let alone opening the database, so they're not opening.

```
parse_ini_file('db.ini') // failed
parse_ini_file('/var/www/html/my_site/db.ini'); // failed
```

4) I've confirmed that the file exists in my php using the following code.

```
$filename = 'db.ini';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

5) Ergo, the import does not appear to be working on my setup (Ubuntu LAMP).

6) On a related not, I tried this as a "require", and saving the variables as db_config.php as well. This did not link up either even though the file exists.

Needless to say, I'm at the end of my rope. Any suggestions? I've a feeling it's a configuration issue, where the script is walled off from communicating with other files on either Apache or my Linux, but have no experience on where to go.

Comment: Can you add the the output of `print_r(parse_ini_file('db.ini'));` to your question? It is far more interesting how it failed than that it failed ;-)

Comment: Or paste whole file included ini reading till mysqli connection.

Comment: The print_r returns nothing (I should have added that). I should maybe edit the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this one [parse_ini_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php).

**Code**

```
$filename = 'db.ini';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $db = parse_ini_string(file_get_contents($filename));
    var_dump($db);
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked, dumping the .ini file contents. All the documents I've read said to use parse_ini_file, not the pasre_ini_string. That's the problem with the internet. Answers could have been asked and answered years ago and no longer work in the current PHP release, [Edit] PS -- I tried to give you an upvote, but need at least 15 karma points.  Sorry...